# arrange a party vs arrange for a party (Is there any difference?)

Tags: verb-usage

> arrange a party vs arrange for a party (Is there any difference?)

The verb 'arrange' can be transitive or intransitive.

Is there any difference?

There is another example: arrange an appointment vs arrange for an appointment

Comment: If you arrange a party, you probably make a lot of the preparations yourself. If you arrange _for_ something, you make it possible for it to happen, but don't necessarily do the work yourself (you might make sure there is a suitable room available, or that people have that evening free, for example).

Comment: Thx. I feel that your use of "probably" means there is no definite distinction between arrange sth and arrange for sth.

Comment: I meant that _arranging_  a social event implies being one of the people who do the actual work of organising it.

Comment: The phrases are different for a reason - they mean different things. You’re making a common ELL mistake - thinking that different things aren’t different.